# Copying over the fields from a ModelForm into a Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a dummy Form that looks like:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    class __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Here's are the ModelForms and their respective Models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)

class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
```

I would like to initiate `MyForm` like this `myfrm = MyForm(PersonForm, AddressForm)`.

How can I dynamically add the fields of each of the Forms to `MyForm` excluding AutoFields and ForeignKey fields i.e. `MyForm` when initiated would have three fields in the end — `fname`, `lname` and `address`. It's a simple copying of the fields from one form to another but I'm a little lost with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a field is not correct, considering the models above.

`Address` has a `ManyToOne` relation to Person - A user can have multiple addresses. In that case better take a look at django's inline form sets:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view

Cumbersome, but You can also manually add a `CharField` to to Person's `ModelForm`, override it's save and handle saving the content of that field to `Address` (ugly, I don't like it).

Answer (score 0):

You can put both forms inside one html `<form>` tag, using the [`prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) argument. You then do a bit of work in the view to link the address to the person.

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        person_form = PersonForm(data=request.POST, prefix="person")
        address_form = AddressForm(data=request.POST, prefix="address")
        if person_form.is_valid() and address_form.is_valid():
            person = person.save()
            address = address.save(commit=False)
            address.person = person
            address.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success-url/')
    ...
```